# How to put all dependencies in separate folder for runnable jar?

Tags: java, maven

I'm using `mvn package` to create a runnable jar with all dependencies packed inside, which runs fine.
But I'd prefer to have all external dependencies packed in a separate folder. What would I have to change therefore?

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>my.MainApp</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: You can get help from the [Copy dependencies Mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `maven-dependencies-plugin` to specify an output directory for the `copy-dependencies` execution.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Update:**

To let the jar know where to find the `lib` folder, you can specify this as a `Class-Path` value in the `manifest` using the `maven-jar-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        <mainClass>foo.bar.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And how will the runnable jar know in which directory to look for the needed dependencies?