# Can I build a seperate dependency JAR and compiled JAR in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar

My development cluster is behind an internet connection which can only be defined as "snail speed" which is making it a very slow process testing my Java application which needs uploading to the cluster on each change.

Is it possible to get Maven to build a JAR containing my compiled classes which I can frequently upload to my server (small JAR) and build a seperate JAR containing my Maven defined dependencies (large JAR) which would only be uploaded when a dependency change occurs? How would I then go about merging the dependencies and compiled classes Jar on the cluster?

Comment: You could follow the advice in this question to have your dependencies in a folder, separate to your JAR: [How to put all dependencies in separate folder for runnable jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23013941)

Comment: I think that is exactly what I need. As the dependencies are seperate to the compiled classes JAR then this will enable me to upload the changes quicker. Thanks Duncan

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single Maven project for your application and you are using the standard convention in Maven, then you already build a jar-file with your compiled classes only. A jar-file is actually the output of a Maven project. If you run

```
mvn install
```

you'll get the compiled classes in a jar-file in

```
<your home dir>\.m2\repository\<yourGroupId>\<yourArtifactId-versionNumber.jar>
```

If you have only changed your own code, then this is all you need to upload to your cluster after a change.

After running `mvn install` on your project, dependencies are installed in

`<your home dir>\.m2\repository\<dependencyGroupId>\<dependencyArtifactId-versionNumber.jar>`

Should you want to copy all your dependencies jars to one specific folder you can use the [Maven Dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and specifically one of the goals [dependency:copy or dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html)

This will give you all the dependencies as separate jar-files. You asked for them to be in one single jar-file and for that I'd recommend the answers to the question: 
[How to put all dependencies in separate folder for runnable jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013941/how-to-put-all-dependencies-in-separate-folder-for-runnable-jar)

However, keeping separate jars also makes it possible for you to only upload changed dependencies. This might make more sense to you since you want to use as little bandwidth as possible to your cluster. Since the dependencies will only change when you change your pom.xml file you'll know when they've changed and that is the only time you'll have to re-upload the dependencies to your cluster. All other times you'll just need to upload your own compiled classes.